# XML AUTO and UNION Issue in SQL Server 2012

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

We're in the process of upgrading the SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 (I know, I know, we're few versions behind, but it's a temporarily solution) to utilize some of the features that are not available in 2008. In the process we identified an issue/difference in how SQL Server 2012 treats XML Auto when UNION statement is present.

Here is the format I'm trying to achieve:

```
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0">
  <ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
</Product>
```

Here is the code that produced the above (using AdventureWorksDB):

```
Select Distinct Product.Color, Product.EnglishProductName, 0 as Customizable,
    ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName,
    ProductSubCategory.FrenchProductSubcategoryName
    From dbo.DimProduct as Product
    Inner Join dbo.DimProductSubcategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey
    For Xml Auto
```

But as soon as as I add UNION statement, it breaks my XML output:

```
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
<Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="1" EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves" FrenchProductSubcategoryName="Gants" />
```

Here is the code that produced the above:

```
Select Distinct Product.Color, Product.EnglishProductName, 0 as Customizable,
ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName,
ProductSubCategory.FrenchProductSubcategoryName
From dbo.DimProduct as Product
Inner Join dbo.DimProductSubcategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey
Union
Select Distinct Product.Color, Product.EnglishProductName, 1 as Customizable,
ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName,
ProductSubCategory.FrenchProductSubcategoryName
From dbo.DimProduct as Product
Inner Join dbo.DimProductSubcategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey
For Xml Auto
```

I need the ProductSubCategory to remain a child of the Product node in the XML output even with UNION statement. The UNION had no effect on the XML output in 2008 but for some reason SQL Server 2012 treats the same statement differently. Any help is appreciated. Hopefully I was clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please provide some sample data in consumable format, best is DDL, INSERT and your working code as *stand-alone MCVE*. This helps as a lot. This time I typed it for you:

Some *mockup tables* with data:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE(ProductKey INT IDENTITY,Color VARCHAR(100),EnglishProductName VARCHAR(100),ProductSubcategoryKey INT);
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES('Black','Full-Finger Gloves, L',1)
                          ,('Black','Full-Finger Gloves, M',1)
                          ,('Black','Full-Finger Gloves, S',1)
                          ,('Black','Half-Finger Gloves, L',1)
                          ,('Black','Half-Finger Gloves, M',1)
                          ,('Black','Half-Finger Gloves, S',1);

DECLARE @ProductSubCategory TABLE(ProductSubcategoryKey INT IDENTITY,EnglishProductSubcategoryName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ProductSubCategory VALUES('Gloves');
```

--The query uses `FOR XML PATH` instead of `AUTO` mode. I'll explain this later

```
Select Distinct Product.Color AS [@Color]
              , Product.EnglishProductName AS [@EnglishProductName]
              , 0 as [@Customizable]
              , ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName AS [ProductSubCategory/@EnglishProductSubcategoryName]
    From @Product as Product
    Inner Join @ProductSubCategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey

UNION 
Select Distinct Product.Color AS [@Color]
              , Product.EnglishProductName AS [@EnglishProductName]
              , 1 as [@Customizable]
              , ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName AS [ProductSubCategory/@EnglishProductSubcategoryName]
    From @Product as Product
    Inner Join @ProductSubCategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey
For Xml PATH('Product');
```

Some explanation:

Your approach with `AUTO` allows the engine to decide what you'll get. In general I dislike such an idea. Any change of the internal implementation can blow up a system in production. Better use `PATH`, which allows you the deepest control on what you'll get.

### Some remarks:

**No union needed**

If I get this correctly, you are using the `UNION` just to add each product twice. One line with a zero at `@Customizable`, the second with a 1. A simple `CROSS JOIN` with a `VALUES` set will do the same, but faster and better to read:

```
Select Distinct Product.Color AS [@Color]
              , Product.EnglishProductName AS [@EnglishProductName]
              , A.Customizable as [@Customizable]
              , ProductSubCategory.EnglishProductSubcategoryName AS [ProductSubCategory/@EnglishProductSubcategoryName]
    From @Product as Product
    Inner Join @ProductSubCategory As ProductSubCategory On ProductSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryKey = Product.ProductSubcategoryKey
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(0)) A(Customizable)
For Xml PATH('Product')
```

**Readability**

It is good to use table-aliases, but I'd suggest to use shorter aliases like here

```
Select Distinct p.Color AS [@Color]
              , p.EnglishProductName AS [@EnglishProductName]
              , A.Customizable as [@Customizable]
              , sc.EnglishProductSubcategoryName AS [ProductSubCategory/@EnglishProductSubcategoryName]
    From @Product as p
    Inner Join @ProductSubCategory As sc On sc.ProductSubcategoryKey = p.ProductSubcategoryKey
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(0)) A(Customizable)
For Xml PATH('Product');
```

**Structure**

Sooner or later you will have a product which is part of more than one SubCategory. I'd suggest to design this as a `n:m` related system with a mapping table in between

**The final XML**

As your SubCategory is more something like a *Product-Family* You might create something like

```
<ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves">
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="1" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="1" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="1" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" Customizable="1" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" Customizable="1" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="0" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" Customizable="1" />    
<ProductSubCategory>
```

Or even simpler

```
<ProductSubCategory EnglishProductSubcategoryName="Gloves">
  <Customizable value=1>
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" />    
  </Customizable>
  <Customizable value=0>
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, L" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, M" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Full-Finger Gloves, S" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, L" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, M" />
    <Product Color="Black" EnglishProductName="Half-Finger Gloves, S" />    
  </Customizable>
<ProductSubCategory>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Even though your post was extremely detailed and helpful, it didn't answer my question. None of your examples produced the XML output I need (please refer to my original post, first example). We have XSLT based website that relies on that specific format to function properly. I realize that UNION example isn't the best but it was just only an example to demonstrate that the XML output breaks when UNION is present in SQL 2012. I'm trying to avoid completely rewriting all statements where we have UNION in our production environment. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I was hoping we can keep the UNION statement but maybe adjust XML call somehow to produced the desired output. I tried playing with XML Path, but I can't seem to produce the needed XML output

Comment: @OlegMuravyov, Might be I've got something wrong, but my code returns - as fair as I see - exactly the needed result... (the XMLs down the line are just examples for a better structure, but you don't need this obviously...). As a simple hack you might want to try a wrapper like here `SELECT * FROM (SELECT blah UNION SELECT blah) FOR XML AUTO` or a CTE like this `WITH cte AS(SELECT blah UNION SELECT blah) SELECT * FROM cte FOR XML AUTO`. But I'd still stay with `PATH` ;-)